# Two customs views being drawn instead of one

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm developing a little app with two custom views in Cocoa. The custom views are controlled by two separated classes. I've a NSTimer set up in my AppDelegate that asks one of the views to draw it self, but the the problem is that both views are being drawn.

My method looks like this:

```
- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    [theOtherView setNeedsDisplay:YES];    // The View that needs to be drawn
    [theBackGroundView setNeedsDisplay:NO];    // Doesn't really do anything, thought it might though.
}
```

I hope someone can point me in a direction to how I should draw my view instead.

Comment: That's probably why. If you look, `-drawRect:` on `theBackGroundView` is probably invoked with a `dirtyRect` that's not the entire view. What's the problem you're having? Is drawing really slow?

Comment: Good overview here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/DrawingEnviron/DrawingEnviron.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH202-SW19

Comment: There isn't really a 'big' problem, but because the background only needs to be redrawn when it is resized, and it's a bit of a complicated background, I thought making two views would save some performance.

I'm pretty sure my `-drawRect:` covers the entire view.

Comment: @rien333: Your implementation might, but what noa is saying is that your background view's `drawRect:` is being passed a `dirtyRect` (`drawRect:`'s argument) that is a section of the view's `bounds`—namely, the rectangle where the two views overlap. You should make your `drawRect:` not draw anything that's entirely outside of that rectangle, if possible.

Comment: Does the foreground view completely overlap the background view, or only partially? If it overlaps completely, have you tried making it a subview of the background view?

Comment: It completely overlaps the other view, sorry for leaving out important information. :) Making it a sub view in IB unfortunately still doesn't help, and calling `addSubView:` doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Sending `addSubview:` yourself is no different from adding it as a subview in the nib editor. What happens if you make the background view layer-backed, and either leave the foreground view as a (non-layer-backed) sibling to it or make it layer-backed (and a subview) as well?

Comment: The latter seems to do the trick, probably due to the caching stuff it goes through, right? Oh, and thanks for the solution.

Comment: @rien333: Pretty much. It is a form of caching, but not as mysterious as you make it sound; a layer-backed view caches the work of its `drawRect:` in its layer's `contents`. You're welcome.